# Multiple bootstrap collapse in a page

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap collapse but I've a problem. The first collapse I insert work fine but when I repaste it at the bottom of the page they are interfering. The second open the first one. I think I must name them differently or doing something like this but I don't know how to do. This is my code:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=2271780003550934014#demo">Hello</a>
<br />
<div class="collapse" id="demo" style="text-align: left;">
Hello
</div>
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Change ID's . For E.g  From demo to demo1 for next.

Comment: I've already test this but it doesn't work...

Comment: No, it works !! Thanks. It was because I haven't replace demo to demo1 in the link.